# Failed to install Ubuntu: drm failed to create kernel channel 22

Tags: system-installation

```
CPU: ryzen 7 3700x
Graphics card: （Colorful) iGame GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER Ultra 6G 1785-1830MHz GDDR6
Motherboard: MSI B450M MORTAR MAX
```

I having trouble booting the installation with USB in UEFI mode，it throw:  `drm failed to create kernel channel 22`, can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually related to the nouveau graphics driver (the error is coming from that driver). It seems to happen on systems where there are no other graphics. For instance, I'm seeing this when trying to boot Ubuntu Desktop on a Supermicro Xeon server that has an NVIDIA GPU. I understand that a work around is to boot the kernel with the "nomodeset" option. Once you get your system installed and the NVIDIA binary driver in you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you used the rufus software for booting your usb. It should work. Try from rufus. Thank you!